# How to call a flask application from a web browser?

Tags: python-2.7, nginx, flask, centos, uwsgi

I have a flask application that works on my PC.
When I deployed it on the virtual server (CentOs 6.5) I used nginx according to the article: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-flask-web-applications-using-uwsgi-behind-nginx-on-centos-6-4

I had to change the port in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf because it created conflict with apache port (caused nginx to fail to start because port is already in use). So my nginx.conf is:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {

    worker_connections 1024;

}

http {

    sendfile on;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   500;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                      text/comma-separated-values
                      text/javascript
                      application/x-javascript
                      application/atom+xml;

    # Configuration containing list of application servers
    upstream uwsgicluster {

        server 127.0.0.1:8081;
        # server 127.0.0.1:8081;
        # ..
        # .

    }

    # Configuration for Nginx
    server {

        # Running port
        listen 81;

        # Settings to by-pass for static files 
        location ^~ /static/  {

            # Example:
            # root /full/path/to/application/static/file/dir;
            root /app/static/;

        }

        # Serve a static file (ex. favico) outside static dir.
        location = /favico.ico  {

            root /app/favico.ico;

        }

        # Proxying connections to application servers
        location / {

            include            uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass         uwsgicluster;

            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

        }
    }
}
```

My application is located under 12.12.15.16/cgi-bin/My_app (the ip address here is dummy).

I used the following command line to start the app:

```
env/bin/uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8081 --protocol=http --wsgi-file main.py --callable app
```

My question is: How can I now call my app from a web browser?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8081`

Answer (score 0):

Your Flask app is listening on port 8081 but only for localhost connections (127.0.0.1). Nginx is listening on port 81 for connections and piping them to Flask on 8081. So from your own browser you want to access `http://your-digital-ocean-ip:81/`